# Where does Homebrew install fontconfig's fonts.conf?

Tags: homebrew, fontconfig

I'm getting an error (when I run Python) that there are some obsolete entries in my Homebrew-installed fontconfig's `fonts.conf`, but don't know where to look for it. (I've checked the [expected locations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontconfig#Configuration), but can't find it there.)

Where does Homebrew install fontconfig's `fonts.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

According to this post (about a fonts.conf warning from Octave):

https://superuser.com/questions/1120758/fontconfig-warning-on-osx-when-running-octave

Homebrew places fonts.conf here:  `/usr/local/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`

I use Homebrew, and indeed there is a `fonts.conf` there, but it dates from 2014 (3 years ago), despite me having just updated/upgraded brew's `fontconfig` (which regenerates the font cache). A search of `/usr/local` indicates the related files that brew *does* update when you do `brew upgrade fontconfig` are:

```
/usr/local/etc/fonts/fonts.conf.default
/usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf.default
```

I did a search of my System drive, and I also found a recent `fonts.conf` here:  `/opt/X11/lib/X11/fontconfig`.  That might be from XQuartz; I'm not sure.

Like you, when running Python (using matplotlib in an IPython session), I got a Fontconfig warning. The specific warning I got was: "blank doesn't take any effect anymore. please remove it from your fonts.conf."  Having seen that brew didn't touch that old `fonts.conf`, I simply renamed it to hide it.  The warning went away, and so far there have been no adverse effects.  I'm guessing matplotlib is now getting its font info from one of the other files.